# When I press a button on an app I made, the app closes and it says unfortunately the app has closed

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to app making, and am making a simple calculator.

Whenever I click a button, I get the message "Unfortunately, Calculator has stopped." Any help would be greatly appreciated.

XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Calculator" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Add"
    android:onClick="DoAdd" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:text="Subtract" 
    android:onClick="DoMinus"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="DoTimes"
    android:text="Multiply" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Java File:

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calculator extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calculator, menu);
    return true;
}

public void doAdd(View v)
{
    EditText firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    double x = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
    double y = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());

    double total = x + y;

    TextView answerSpace = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    answerSpace.setText(Double.toString(total));
}
}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Where's the stacktrace?

Comment: android:onClick="DoAdd"  is giving you the error, because it does not exist in your java code, be careful with the upper/lowercases android:onClick="doAdd"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your xml `onClick` attribute to exactly match the method name in your java code:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
...
android:onClick="doAdd" />
```

Notice the lower-case `d` at the beginning.

If those two don't match, the app crashes while Android is trying to invoke the onClick method you specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
FD_ already pointed out the mistake from your code.

But for better coding approach you can follow this. If you wish.

In your xml file, define single method name for onClick on each button ie for
addition,substration,division,multiplication.

What i mean to say...?

// For Addition....

<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
  android:text="Add"
  android:onClick="calculate" />

 //Define android:onClick="calculate" for remaining 3 buttons

 ie say for subtraction 

 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
  android:text="Subract"
  android:onClick="calculate" /> 

 do similarly for division and multiplication


 Now, in Java File

 1)Define Variables globally
 2)Find their ids in onCreateMethod(), ie when the activity created.

 How to do this?


 public class Calculator extends Activity
 {
  EditText firstNumber,secondNumber;

    onCreate()
   {
     firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   }

   public void calculate(View v)
   {

    switch(v.getId())
      {

         case R.id.button1:
              // Do coding here addition....
              break;
          case R.id.button2:
              // Do coding here substraction....
              break;
          case R.id.button3:
              // Do coding here multiplication....
              break;
          case R.id.button4:
              // Do coding here division....
              break;

      }
   }


 }
```